# Is there any way to have a [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] method in a standard page in c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, webmethod

Is there any way to have a [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] method in a standard page in c#?

I have a c# ASPX page that I would like to have a a method for my ajax to call. I want everything to be self contained in a single file for organization and deployment purposes.

When I add that directive to a System.Web.UI.Page for example:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetText()
{
    return "All finished!";
}
```

and try to call Page.aspx/GetText I get the full page back, not just "All Finished" as expected.

The javascript the ajax is via jQuery:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function () {
    var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 250);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.aspx/GetText",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 100);
            $("#result").text(msg.d);
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: could you paste your javascript code to that method?

Answer (score 0):

These are called "Page Methods". See"[Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx)".